# nginx how can properly setting public domain names for Django apps with gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have set up nginx for Djnago apps with gunicorn on ubuntu 20.04 by following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04), and as result of this, the site works locally with local domain name. But after buying public domain name, I can not manage how to set up this public domain name with my nginx server. And I take this error on browsers: [image]

How can see the domains which are requested on nginx server? In addition, I can access to nginx server by vps server IP.

Comment: Did you create an A record for the DNS to point to your server?

Comment: @Walucas I bought the domain name from one company, and they said they done it for my vps server ip. It is enough?

Comment: no... you need to have an A record to your domain, that how websites got resolved into IPs

Comment: @Walucas It can be done on vps server side or from domain settings (I found many tutorials which teach do it from domain side, is it true?)?

Comment: Not sure I understand... domain is one thing, server is another.... you have your server running django on a public IP.... the DNS needs to point to this IP